# Pricing over BigQuery tables data

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to clear a doubt about charges or pricing. Whether BigQuery Charges on one of the following scenarios:-

1) If my table contains 100 GB of data and if i query over this table to search for a record and BigQuery traverses 100 GB to find that record. In this case Traversal Charges.

OR

2) If my query returns a result set of 90 GB from 100 GB. In this case amount of data retrieved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery only charges for the data processed (or as you say, 'traversed') in the columns you SELECT and from the table you specify.

For example, if you have a table called '`my_table`' with fields '`a,b,c,d,e`'

And your SELECT statement is:

```
SELECT sum(a), sum(b) from [my_table];
```

This query will only charge for the amount of data in column `a` and `b`... not `c,d, or e`. Aside from processing, BigQuery also charges for storage of data in the system.

For more on BigQuery pricing, please the [our pricing page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/pricing).

Comment: Thanks. Now, i can start my project.